# Scraping only first page reviews - Beautiful Soup (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need some help scraping all the reviews posted for one product on random website (M&S here). But it scrapes only the 1st page reviews only where it has around 900 reviews on it. And even the URL doesn't change if we go on to next page of reviews). Below is the coding.

And i can extract only the month along with year as date, Is there any way to find out the review posted date.

Any suggestions would be really helpful.
Thanks.

[Code for scraping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4wug.png)
[Reviews](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahpug.png)

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks   - On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The product pages](https://www.marksandspencer.com/pure-cotton-slogan-sweatshirt/p/clp60593727) fetch reviews with Javascript POST to https://prod.prod.gql-mesh.gql.mnscorp.net/graphql , a [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/learn/) backend. The POST body contains the generic GraphQL query and its variables, like product id, `limit` of reviews per page, and pagination `offset`.

Use your browser devtools to copy a valid request., then try sending requests for `limit=10&offset=0`, `limit=10&offset=10`, `limit=10&offset=20`, etc.

And by sending a POST request to this backend instead of GET'ing the website, you also get an easy-to-parse response in JSON format. It contains precise fields like `"submissionTime": "2023-03-23T09:34:06.000+00:00"` for each review.

Comment: Hi BoppreH, Thanks for your reply. I am a bit new to Python coding and Scraping. Could you please elaborate a bit on the above process. It would be really helpful if you can do so.

Comment: Sure. Go to a product page with your browser's devtools open in the Network tab, and look at the request to the GraphQL URL I posted above. Copy the request body, and send a POST request to that URL with the request body that you copied. It should give you 10 reviews for that product, in easy-to-parse JSON format. Change the `offset` to see different pages, and the `id` to get reviews for different products.

Comment: Hi BoppreH, Is this is the right URL i need to raise request for?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3RpT.png

Comment: I am trying to search graphql from the devtools going to network tab but couldn't find the link. Please have a look. https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5CNY.png

Comment: The URL is in my answer. And make sure you open the reviews with the devtools network tab already open.

Comment: Hi BoppreH, I got the json response reviews. But instead of increasing this offset by 10 for every 10 reviews. Is there any way to get all the reviews at once. Because, for some there might be more than 2000 reviews and would be hard to send combine all these together.

Comment: You can bump the "limit" parameter to get more at once, but there might be a server-enforced maximum value. So `limit=2000` might or might not work.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply BoppreH, The max limit here is 20. So, In this case do we need to gradually keep on increasing the offset and combine all into one table or is there any way to get all at once.